calculating rotation matrix and translation vector
I have some camera parameters, from there I can get the intrinsic parameters matrix, but I     didn't know how to calculate the extrinsic parameters without knowing the real world coordinates. I want to obtain the projection matrix by calculating R and t. I will use this matrix in a visual  odometry project.

The results of  the code I tried for visual odometry in the kitti dataset and when I counted the t vector as 0, the  results I obtained in the kitti dataset were quite accurate, but since there is such complexity in  my own dataset, the problem is in the parameters.
Here are the parameters I have:
cameraParameters with properties:

Camera Intrinsics
IntrinsicMatrix: \[3×3 double\]
FocalLength: \[1.4133e+03 1.4188e+03\]
PrincipalPoint: \[950.0639 543.3796\]
Skew: 0
RadialDistortion: \[-0.0091 0.0666\]
TangentialDistortion: \[0 0\]
ImageSize: \[1080 1920\]

Camera Extrinsics
RotationMatrices: \[3×3×33 double\]
TranslationVectors: \[33×3 double\]

Accuracy of Estimation
MeanReprojectionError: 0.6450
ReprojectionErrors: \[80×2×33 double\]
ReprojectedPoints: \[80×2×33 double\]

Calibration Settings
NumPatterns: 33
WorldPoints: \[80×2 double\]
WorldUnits: 'millimeters'
EstimateSkew: 0
NumRadialDistortionCoefficients: 2
EstimateTangentialDistortion: 0


Mathworks recommends using cameraProjection function instead of cameraMatrix. Which one are you using?

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameramatrix.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_camera%20rotation%20matrix

reduce complexity. verify your approach and implementation on synthetic data. then you can be somewhat confident that your real data is handled right.

@JohnBofarullGuix I did not obtain these parameters myself, and I do not have a camera of these parameters. These are the parameters shared by the contest organizers for a contest. That's all I know about these. Secondly, these are the parameters for the camera of a drone flying at a fixed altitude with a fixed perspective of 90 degrees to the ground.


You are right, to proceed you need a coordinates system reference and at least 1 calibration image, besides the input image.

As explained here
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameramatrix.html?s_tid=srchtitle_site_search_1_camera%20rotation%20matrix
Please run the following Mathworks lines on your image.
It's assumed you have the Vision toolbox.
Generating calibration images
images = imageDatastore(fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'),'visiondata','calibration','slr'));

Using the chess board as calibration image.
Getting the corners of the chess board
[imagePoints,boardSize] = detectCheckerboardPoints(images.Files);

Generating coordinates system referene
squareSize = 29; 
worldPoints = generateCheckerboardPoints(boardSize,squareSize);


I = readimage(images,1); 
imageSize = [size(I,1),size(I,2)];
cameraParams = estimateCameraParameters(imagePoints,worldPoints,'ImageSize',imageSize);

moving the input image, not the calibration one, the data you have, to a different position
imOrig = imread(fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','vision','visiondata','calibration','slr','image9.jpg'));
figure; imshow(imOrig);
title('Input Image');

im = undistortImage(imOrig,cameraParams);

[imagePoints,boardSize] = detectCheckerboardPoints(im);

[rotationMatrix,translationVector] = extrinsics(imagePoints,worldPoints,cameraParams);

P = cameraMatrix(cameraParams,rotationMatrix,translationVector)

